# Android-vision how get stream from camera using G.P.Services vision package in api level 19

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, vision

I am working with android vision package from google play services. I triying to get frame or bitmap or raw images anyone.

Actually my app can detect faces and draw rectangles around.
I use the oficialsample of google >vision>facetracker .

I want to use it with opencv 2.4.3 donc I am forced to use api level 19 and deprecated camera api.
How I can get the  stream of camera for modify it. I not wont take picture, I tried and is slow.

Comment: I don't quite understand. you want an image from your camera but you don't want to take a picture? that makes no sense.

Comment: You can use JavaCameraView which uses old camera api as far as I remember and implement CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener. There you can take bytes from Mat and convert it into YUV needed by google vision and send it to processing in other thread. Then you can draw stuff on JavaCameraView canvas like on graphic overlay in vision examples.

Answer (score 0):

No . I wan to get the bitmap stream from camera before it is send to surface.